# How to get an image on the desired page by clicking on that image using Laravel?

Tags: php, html, charts, laravel-5

I am working on the laravel 5.0. I am getting an error: "trying to get property of non-object".I want to get an image on the desired page by clicking on that particular image. There are so many images on the page, i just want after clicking on any image, it will be appear on the desired page.
here is my code:

My Routes:

```
 Route::get('/image/big/{id}' ,[
  'uses'=>'GalleryController@bigimage',
  'as'=>'bigimage'
  ]);
```

My controller:

```
public function bigimage($id){

$images=image::findorFail($id);
return view('bigimage' , ['images'=>$images]);
}
```

My view from where i am calling the required Route:

```
 @foreach($gallery->images as $image)
  <li>
  <a href="{{ URL('/image/big/'.$image->id) }}">
  <img id="jumboimage2" src="{{    url($image->file_path) }}"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
  <a href="{{ URL('/image/delete/'.$image->id) }}" id="margin">
  <span id="margin" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span></a>
  </li>
  @endforeach
```

My view where i want to get the required image:

```
  <div class="row">
  <section class="col-md-3">
  @foreach($images as $image)
  {{$image->id}}
  @endforeach
  </section>
  </div>
```

Comment: I think the problem is in this line `$gallery->images` perhaps because the `$gallery` in null !!

Comment: No, i am passing the $gallery variable through another Route and function. so, it may not be the reason.

Comment: What is the actual error here? Please provide more information

Comment: Actually, i want to get an image on the required page after clicking on an image. That image will be shown on the required page on which i am clicking and also , when i am clicking on that image, i am calling its id too from my database where that image is stored..

Comment: error is :  Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\wamp64\www\gal\resources\views\bigimage.blade.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try this one out



$image = image::findOrFail($id);


return view('bigimage' , ['image' => $image])
```

Answer (score 0):

`$images=image::findorFail($id);` should be `$images=image::findOrFail($id);`.

`findOrFail()` returns a single model, i.e. one image, so I would have:

```
$image = image::findOrFail($id);
return view('bigimage' , ['image' => $image]);
```

You don't show where `image::` comes from, however usually this is from a facade so is `Image::` with a capital.

The view would then not have the `@foreach` loop as you'd only have a single image.

```
<div class="row">
    <section class="col-md-3">
        {{$image->id}}
    </section>
</div>
```

You also need to elaborate on this to get from the id to an image but I'm assuming that's just not shown.

If you were able to give some detail about which line is causing the error this would make it easier to diagnose, as indicated by Maraboc there could be an issue with `$gallery` as well.

Comment: thanx! it is working fine now. Now, i am getting the required image. I got my error too.